# Storing links retrieved from multiple pages in a single variable in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I would like to extract links from an URL that has multiple pages and store all of the extracted links in a single variable. Now, I have a working code for most of this, however, my created variable only stores the info retrieved from the last page. How can I adjust the code to store the links retrieved from all of the pages?

Here is my code:

```
page_links <- paste0('https://cryptoslate.com/ico-database/recent-icos/page/', 1:7)
# Retrieving links to all pages I want to retrieve links from 

ICO_links_CS <- c()
# Creating an empty variable for links to be stored in 

# loop through each page, extract all links and select the ones I want to 
retrieve, then doing some cleaning up  
for (i in length(page_links)) {
  ICO_links_CS <- c(ICO_links_CS, deduped.data_Cryptoslate)
  page_links_1 <- read_html(page_links[i])
  Extractlinks <- html_attr(html_nodes(page_links_1, "a"), "href")
  ICO_links_Cryptoslate <- str_subset(Extractlinks, 
"https://cryptoslate.com/coins/")
  deduped.data_Cryptoslate <- unique(ICO_links_Cryptoslate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you actually want `for (i in 1:length(page_links))`, not `for (i in length(page_links))`. In addition, rather than appending results from each page to `ICO_links_CS`, you might want to initialize `ICO_links_CS` as a list, and store results from each page as an element in the list. For example,

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

# Retrieving links to all pages I want to retrieve links from 
page_links <- paste0('https://cryptoslate.com/ico-database/recent-icos/page/', 1:7)

# Creating an empty variable for links to be stored in 
ICO_links_CS <- vector(length = length(page_links), mode = "list")

# loop through each page, extract all links and select the ones I want to retrieve, then doing some cleaning up  
for (i in 1:length(page_links)) {
  page_links_1 <- read_html(page_links[i])
  Extractlinks <- html_attr(html_nodes(page_links_1, "a"), "href")
  ICO_links_Cryptoslate <- str_subset(Extractlinks, "https://cryptoslate.com/coins/")
  ICO_links_CS[[i]] <- unique(ICO_links_Cryptoslate)
}
```

Finally,

```
ICO_links_CS <- unlist(ICO_links_CS)
str(ICO_links_CS)
# chr [1:661] "https://cryptoslate.com/coins/"
```